# Add row number to column string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following basic pandas dataframe:

```
df:
            Name    Category    Rank
    0     John        A         nan
    1     Mick        A         nan
    2     Tess        A         nan
    3     Jackie      A         nan
    4     Tash        A         nan
```

I would like a string in the rank column so it reads:

```
        Name    Category    Rank
0     John        A         A1
1     Mick        A        A2
2     Tess        A        A3
3     Jackie      A        A4
4     Tash        A        A5
```

I have tried `df['Rank'] =df['Rank'].fillna("A"+str(df.index.values+1))` but it gives me all the index values.

Im sure there is an easy way but I cant seenm to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More safe in case you have multiple different category

```
df['Rank'] = df.Category + df.groupby('Category').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df
Out[232]: 
     Name Category Rank
0    John        A   A1
1    Mick        A   A2
2    Tess        A   A3
3  Jackie        A   A4
4    Tash        A   A5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['Rank'] = df['Category'] + (np.arange(len(df)) + 1).astype(str)
OR
df['Rank'] = df['Category'] + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods of solving this problem.

1. the simplest

   `df['Rank1'] = df['Category'] + (df.reset_index().index+1).astype(str)`
2. professional

   `df['Rank2'] = df['Category'] + (np.arange(df.shape[0])+1).astype(str)`

or

```
df['Rank3'] = df['Category'] + (np.arange(len(df))+1).astype(str)
```

3. another

   `df.insert(loc=0, column='Rank4', value=df['Category'] + np.arange(len(df))+1).astype(str))`